# Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Int>' to expected argument type 'Binding<_>'

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to create a `TabView` in SwiftUI with following code:

```
@State var selection = 0

var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selection) {
        DataGridPage(type: "media").tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "photo.on.rectangle")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
        }
        .tag(1)

        DataGridPage(type: "files").tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "doc.on.doc")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
        }
        .tag(2)
    }
}
```

But I'm receiving error `Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Int>' to expected argument type 'Binding<_>'`. I see that the variable `selection` is integer, which is the correct type but the warning is still there for some reason.

Answer (score 19):

I figured out the problem. The thing is that `TabView` shows this error even if there is some error in the closure. So the code of creating the `TabView` is correct but the problem is the way I'm initialising `DataGridPage`. I changed the name of the property `type` to `data` inside `DataGridPage` but here I'm still using `type` property. I fixed it and it stopped showing me the warning.

I think SwiftUI is a new framework and it has still a lot improvement to do in terms of debugging. I hope it will mature in future and we would be able to pin point the exact error instead of this vague statement.

The new code now looks like this:

```
@State var selection = 0

var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selection) {
        DataGridPage(data: "media").tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "photo.on.rectangle")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
        }
        .tag(1)

        DataGridPage(data: "files").tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "doc.on.doc")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
        }
        .tag(2)
    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone facing similar problem.

Comment: Had the same problem and could solve it now. Thanks

Comment: My problem seemed similar, but I did not remember to construct my view (parentheses). So it was like I did 

    DataGridPage.tabItem { ... 

instead of 

    DataGridPage().tabItem { ...

In my case, the view did not take any parameters in the constructor.